# CSS - How to achieve a mixed effect of "float left" and "text-align: center"?

Tags: html, css

This is fairly a simple question but I cant wrap my head around a simple solution. I need to center 3 squares in a row, but I dont know the total amount of squares (while the simple solution to this would be to use `text-align: center`), BUT I dont want to center the last elements. Long story short, how to create `float: left` effect + centering all elements inside the main container?

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ny4ph398/).
HTML:

```
<div class="row b">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="row maxW b">
      <div class="postContainer"></div>
      <div class="postContainer"></div>
      <div class="postContainer"></div>
      <div class="postContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .postContainer {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .maxW {
    max-width: 900px;
  }

  .ce {
    text-align: center;
  }

.b{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Expected result:
These squares should be responsive, max squares per row is 3. If I use `float: left`, I get almost what I need, but the squares are pulled to the left and not centered inside the main container. If I use `text-align: center`, the squares are centered in the main container, but I dont want the last squares to be centered, they must remain floated to the left.
[image]

Comment: I didn't get your question.

Comment: Can you draw the expected result?

Comment: I added some more description + expected result. @KalpeshSingh.

Comment: I got your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using flexbox. It's a pretty new concept in css, but it has [good support in all modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). I personally use it in production.

The markup would be simplified as:

```
<div class="posts">
  <div class="postContainer"></div>
  <div class="postContainer"></div>
  <div class="postContainer"></div>
  <div class="postContainer"></div>
</div>
```

And the container would have the CSS:

```
.posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

`Display: flex` tells the browser it's a flexbox, `flex-flow` says that it should be rows that wraps when full and that the content should be left-aligned by `flex-start`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ny4ph398/2/)

[Flexbox basics](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the container width to 33% and then set the post border and width on a contained div.

```
.postContainer {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.post {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9597cLq/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float`.

You CSS would look something like this:

```
.maxW{
        border:1px solid black; 
        padding:5px;
      }

.postContainer{
               width:150px;
               height:150px;
               border:1px solid black; 
               display:inline-block; /* <-- the magic part*/
               }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/048vu2t4/)

Comment: Not quite, I wanted to center the elements in a row as well.